# Prevent anchor parent element from click event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, anchor

I have a span element inside of an anchor element. On the span element is an click event. When I click the span and trigger the event it also triggers the anchor parent element.

I already tried it with `event.stopPropagation();` but with no effect.

Here is an code example

Markup:

```
<a href="#">
    <span class="child"></span>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var children = document.getElementsByClassName("child");

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    children[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("test");
    }, false);
}
```

Result:
clicking the span event triggers the click event function and the parent anchor element.

---

This is the actual code.

Clicking on the red child element triggers the anchor parent and the actual click event.

```js
var deleteButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("delete");

for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
  deleteButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("test");
  }, false);  
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 32px;
  margin: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #CCD0D9;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all .2s 
}

.text {
  color: #000;
}

.delete {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: tomato; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <span class="text">title</span>
    <span class="delete"></span>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <span class="text">title</span>
    <span class="delete"></span>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <span class="text">title</span>
    <span class="delete"></span>
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.google.com/">
    <span class="text">title</span>
    <span class="delete"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? Your code looks fine. What makes you think the `a`'s click event is also firing?

Comment: Please share the original code because I recreated the effect using the code you provided and it worked properly (the message that gets printed in the console only gets printed when I click on the span) not the anchor

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added an code snipped with the actual code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` is the one you are looking for. Still your markup doesn't make sense. If you don't want the anchor tag to be clicked, make it div or something. or add the on click function to the anchor tag itself.

Comment: the idea behind the markup:
I have an clickable anchor element, which leads to an other page.
But inside this element is an smaller element (in the upper right corner) with an other function. This smaller child element should react on an click event and not the parents hyperlink.

event.preventDefault() sadly doesn't work as well.

Comment: It wouldn't work that way. You can either make the child work or anchor tag work. Change the markup and move the child(which is clickable) out of the anchor tag. You can make it look like it is inside anchor tag by doing the CSS cheat.